# portaudio video/audio sync

Tags: portaudio

I use ffmpeg to decode video/audio stream and use portaudio to play audio. I encounter a sync problem with portaudio. I have a function like below,

```
double AudioPlayer::getPlaySec() const  
{  
    double const latency = Pa_GetStreamInfo( mPaStream )->outputLatency;  
    double const bytesPerSec = mSampleRate * Pa_GetSampleSize( mSampleFormat ) * mChannel;  
    double const playtime = mConsumedBytes / bytesPerSec;  
    return playtime - latency;  
}
```

mCousumeBytes is the byte count which written into audio device in the portaudio callback function. I thought I could have got the playing time according to the byte count. Actually, when I execute the other process ( like open firefox ) which make cpu busy, the audio become intermittent, but the callback doesn't stop so that mConsumeBytes is more than expected, and getPlaySec return a time which is larger than playing time.
I have no idea how this happened. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Latency, in PortAudio is defined a bit vaguely. Something like the average time between when you put data into the buffer and when you can expect it to play. That's not something you want to use for this purpose.

Instead, to find the current playback time of the device, you can actually poll the device using the [Pa_GetStreamTime](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a3d9c4cbda4e9f381b76f287c3de8a758) function.

You may want to see [this document](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/portaudio_sync_acmc2003.pdf) for more detailed info.

Comment: I found some thing wrong in my sync logic. It was not caused by portaudio. However, you provided a great document! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But still; PortAudio v19+ can provide you with its own sample rate. You should use that for audio sync, since actual sample rate playback can differ between different hardware. PortAudio might try to compensate (depending on implementation). If you have drift problems, try using that.